# How can I send the string Android to WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Here is my Java code for WebView

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String value1 = "Hello World"; // This is My String
    nWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webapp);
    WebSettings webSettings = nWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    nWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ytd.html");
    nWebView.setWebViewClient(new android.webkit.WebViewClient());
```

How can I send "String value1" to WebView HTML code

And also how to Get The string value1 in my HTML code
Does anyone have the answer?? Please help me

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly, what u mean by sending the string to webview?

Comment: yes i want to send the string to webview

Comment: what else have you tried?